# Third syntax version of LogitModelFit: unexpected result of "BestFit"

Tags: fitting, pure-function

The third listed syntax version of `LogitModelFit` allows one to specify input in a simple way: Only a design matrix (with a row of values of the explanatory input variables for each of the output values) and a response vector are needed. The following example is straight from the `LogitModelFit` help page:

```
dm = {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}};
resp = {0, 1, 0, 1};
model = LogitModelFit[{dm, resp}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

As usual in these types of fits, Mathematica returns an object that can be interrogated with various methods. In this case, I just want to have the best fit:

```
model["BestFit"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I noted something here that I feel is strange. Although this looks like a pure function (which is what I expected, given no formal variable names are specified in this syntax), it really isn't, since the required `&` at the end is missing. Hence, a construction like `model["BestFit"][1,2]` doesn't work.

Is this a bug, or is this useful in some way and am I missing something?

I note that neither the `"Function"` method of `LogitModelFit` nor something like `model//Normal` yields anything useful. The former generates an error which suggests to me that there is indeed a bug in this syntax variant. The latter returns the same as `"BestFit"`.

My workaround for now is to use:

```
mod = model["BestFit"] // Evaluate // Function;
```

(`Evaluate` because of the `HoldAll` attribute of function)

```
mod[1, 2]
```

> 0.3883882668

Comment: I confirm this behavior in *Mathematica* 8.0.4 under Windows 7 x64. Looks like a bug.

Comment: Why would you not just use `model[1,2]` in the example? I don't think this is a bug...

Comment: @rasher I think you are right and I interpreted things wrong here. My initial assumption was that the intention of the "BestFit" parameter was to get you a pure function to work with. I didn't realize that the model itself is already such a pure function. I guess the output for "BestFit" just resembles a pure function because in this syntax variant there are no named variables and `Slot` is used instead.

Comment: @rasher On second thought, there is a very good reason not to use `model[1,2]` and that is that the `FittedModel` doesn't store the actual fit, but calculates it on the fly when called with arguments. This means that it will be actually very slow. In the above example `model[1,2]` is about 150 times slower than my proposed `mod[1,2]`. I expect that it slowness will increase with increasing model complexity and data size. So, you really need a "BestFit" output if you're going to use the model often.

Comment: model["Function"][1,2] works on the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @bobthechemist In my v9 [it doesn't](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hxElZ.png).

Comment: Right, for me neither - I was perhaps too terse and meant to indicate that it does look like a bug and it does look like it will be fixed in v10.

Comment: @rasher Just for fun, compare `model[1,2]//Trace` with `mod[1,2]//Trace`.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: As *bobthechemsist* notes, there is a "Function" property which is the pure function - but I think it (and many of the other properties) are intended as *diagnostics* only. Perhaps open a ticket with WRI to get a more definitive answer?

Comment: @rasher Didn't you see my link about that in the comment above? That doesn't work in v9.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: Yes, that's what I meant by the "diagnostics" reference. BTW, your "divine intervention" comment on the bible text search question elsewhere just made me spew my tea all over my netbook from laughter :-)

Comment: @rasher ;) ;) ;)